# <project-name>/<controllel-name> not found

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am a newbie to Zend Franmework. I have done complete setup for Zend.
Inside the application folder, i have created a Controller using the command

```
                       zf create controller Test
```

which created the controller file.
Apart from this, it also created the view file(i.e. inside application/view/scripts) named index.phtml

My project name is myproj. when i am writing "/myproj" in  browser, it it opening the project Home page.
But when i am opening the page with new generated controller i.e. "myproj/test", it is giving Page not found error..
What am i missing??

I have watched this tutorial.. http://www.youtube.com/user/spamitovic85

Comment: Go through the [Official Quick Start](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.html). I suspect that your rewrite rules are not working. Make sure your [virtual host](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html#learning.quickstart.create-project.vhost) configuration is setup correctly, and also your [`.htaccess` rewrite rules](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.rewrite.html)

Comment: Also, see: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23925/discussion-between-okeyxyz-and-david-weinraub

Comment: Thanks for ur respnse.... I have made wrong entry in my httpd.conf file  inside <VirTualHost> tag.. I have changed it and now my problem is solved. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fire this command you have to copy paste bin folder in your project **myproj** after that this will work